# MDX query on a single dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

Can someone please remind me how I do this?

I want an MDX query (MS SSAS) which will query a dimension.  Not interested in cubes or measures.

So far as I remember the syntax involves a $ sign, something like [$MyDimension].

I know I can do the below, but I want to query the dimension without touching a cube.

```
select [DimensionName].Children on 0 from [CubeName]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess they're called "dimension cube":

```
select [dim].members on 0 from [$dim]
```

or

```
select [Measures].defaultMember on 0, [dim].members on 1 from [$dim]
```

Comment: Marc you are awesome! This is hard to google, but now we have it here on SO to refer back to.

Comment: Keep in mind you do need to be an Administrator (Role) to query a dimension in this way

Comment: Belated appreciation for covering a badly-documented feature. +1